# Javascript function call to have optional attributes

Tags: javascript, function, attributes, function-calls

Can a function be defined in javascript in a way that attributes are optional in a function call?

for example, I have the below function defined:

```
function abc(x1,y1,x2,y2){
//execution
}
```

What I am willing to do is something like this:

```
function abc(x1,y1,x2,y2,id){
if(id!=''){
//do something
}else{
// do something else
}
}
```

**function call: abc(1,2,3,4);**

Will the above function still work or give an error?

Comment: `id` will never be `''`, unless you pass an empty string. Use strict comparing against `undefined` instead.

Comment: This are called parameters.

Comment: All parameters are optional in javascript. Default value for they is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it as `typeof id !== 'undefined'`

```js
function abc(x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {
  if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(id);
  } else {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
}

abc(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log('-------------------');
abc(1, 2, 3, 4, 'YOUR_ID');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first response on StackOverflow.

```
function miOptionalFunction(a, b, optionalParameter) {
    if (optionalParameter === undefined) {
        optionalParameter = "defect value";
    } else {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting comes in time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can have an optional parameter have a default value if it is not passed in to the function.

```
function test(a, b, c = false) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript a function has a built-in object called **arguments**, you can use it like this :

```
function abc( x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {
   if ( arguments.length > 4 ) {
       //do something
   } else {
       // do something else
   }
}
```

you can find more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)